scale_x_discrete doesn't work in ggeffects
I"d like to customise my x-axis using scale_x_discrete, but in plot, using ggeffects doesn't work.
In my example:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggeffects)
library(datawizard)
data(efc, package = "ggeffects")
efc$c172code <- datawizard::to_factor(efc$c172code)
fit <- lm(barthtot ~ c12hour + neg_c_7 + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)
# categorical variables have errorbars
dat <- predict_response(fit, terms = c("c172code", "c161sex"))
plot(dat) + scale_x_discrete(labels=c("high level of education","intermediate level of education","low level of education")) 



Please, any help with it?

See also the docs on this topic: https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_plotcustomize.html

Specifying factor levels before plotting is probably the most straightforward approach. However, in case you want to fiddle around with the plot further, it may be helpful to create it from the ggeffect object "manually".
dat |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  ggplot(aes(x = x,
             y = predicted,
             ymin = conf.low,
             ymax = conf.high,
             color = group)) +
  geom_pointrange(position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +
  labs(x = "carer's level of education",
       y = "Total score BARTHEL INDEX",
       color = "carer's gender") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red','blue')) +
  theme_bw() 


Created on 2024-05-31 with reprex v2.1.0

It is likely easier to prep your efc$c172code column as a factor with the desired level order and overall label attribute prior to further work:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggeffects)

data(efc, package = "ggeffects")

efc$c172code <- factor(
  efc$c172code,
  levels = 3:1,
  labels = c(
    "high level of education",
    "intermediate level of education",
    "low level of education"
  )
)
attr(efc$c172code, "label") <- "carer's level of education"

fit <- lm(barthtot ~ c12hour + neg_c_7 + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)
dat <- predict_response(fit, terms = c("c172code", "c161sex"))
plot(dat)


Created on 2024-05-31 with reprex v2.1.0
